# Using boost condition variables

Tags: c++, boost

I am designing an asynchronous logger class as follows. However, not sure if I am using the  boost condition variable in the right way. Can anyone comment on this? Here the processLogEntry method is a thread function and I am using boost here.

```
void LogWriter::stopThread()
{
    mStop = true;
    mCond.notify_one();
    mThread->join();
}   

void LogWriter::processLogEntry()
{
    while(!mStop)
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mMutex);
        mCond.wait(lock);
        while(!q.empty())
        {
            // process begins
        }
    }
}

void LogWriter::addLogEntry()
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mMutex);
    // add it in the queue
    mCond.notify_one();
}
```

Comment: one obvious problem in your code is that `mStop` suffers from race condition, which can be amended by using `atomic<>` variable. Also please also update your code with how you push logs to the queue (I guess?) `q`, to let us better understand your problem.

Comment: I am using volatile bool for mStop. Even then it will be a problem?

Comment: mStop does not suffer from a race condition since it is only modified by stopThread, and stopThread waits that the thread finishes before returning.

Comment: @sylvain.joyeux His code using `mStop` is undefined behavior, since the variable is accessed by more than one thread.  It must be either an atomic variable, or the accesses must be synchronized.

Comment: mStop is a true/false variable which is written only by one thread and read only by one thread. The thread that reads the variable can only see a transition from false to true since the thread that sets the condition to true joins. This is *not* undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it has been pointed out, you must either make `mStop` atomic or guard *all* its accesses with the mutex. Forget about `volatile`, it's not relevant to your purposes.

Furthermore, when waiting on a condition variable a call to `wait` may return even if no notification functions were called (those are so-called spurious wake-ups). As such, calls to `wait` need to be guarded.

```
void LogWriter::stopThread()
{
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mMutex);
        mStop = true;
        mCond.notify_one();
    }
    mThread->join();

}   

void LogWriter::processLogEntry()
{
    for(;;) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mMutex);
        // We wait as long as we're not told to stop and
        // we don't have items to process
        while(!mStop && q.empty()) mCond.wait(lock);

        // Invariant: if we get here then
        // mStop || !q.empty() holds

        while(!q.empty())
        {
            // process begins
        }

        if(mStop) return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. could you let me know how to make mStop atomic? does boost has some data type of that kind?

Comment: @user243655 I don't know of a portable C++03 solution. (IIRC there is a Boost.Atomic library under review.) So you may want to check what's available on your system.